# Pass URL parameter from JSP to Servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

So I have a JSP with a randomly generated "key" inside the URL, which will be something like this:

```
url.com/reset.jsp?key=1234
```

And my JSP has two text inputs inside a form

```
<form action="ResetServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="firstname" size="24" value="">
<input type="text" name="lastname" size="24" value="">
</form>
```

And I'm trying to send the 3 parameters: Key from URL, user input of "firstname", and user input of "lastname" to my Java Servlet code. How do I read the 3 parameters from my Servlet code? Can anyone point me to a tutorial or explain how I could do that? Thanks.

**EDIT:**
So I wrote the following simple servlet code:

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    String firstname = request.getParameter("firstname");
    String lastname = request.getParameter("lastname");
    String key = request.getParameter("key");

    response.setContentType("text/html");

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.println("<h1>" + "Hello: " + firstname + " " + lastname + ". key: " + key + "</h1>");
}
```

And it displays:

> Hello: null null. key: null

No matter what I input. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://met.guc.edu.eg/OnlineTutorials/JSP%20-%20Servlets/A%20servlet%20example.aspx

Comment: updated answer below, works now

Answer (score 1):

Just save the `key` parameter in the form when the page renders.

```
<!-- declare at top of JSP -->
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<form action="ResetServlet" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type="text" name="firstname" size="24" value="">
  <input type="text" name="lastname" size="24" value="">

  <input type="hidden" name="key" value="<c:out value='${param.key}'/>">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use HttpServletRequest.getParameter(String) method. For example,

```
public class ResetServlet extends HttpServlet {
  protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname");
    String lastName  = request.getParameter("lastname");
    String key       = request.getParameter("key");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One can read parameter from query string using request.getParameter("variable_name");

in your case it will be

```
.....doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
  String firstName = request.getParameter("firstname");
  String lastName  = request.getParameter("lastname");
  String key       = request.getParameter("key");
}
```

Comment: I think it should work..please do check action and path properly.

Comment: Will you please post your web.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove  enctype part in form tag.